# How to close child/nested dialog using matDialogClose instead of parent dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having a two dialogs with a sort of parent-child relationship. Parent is a standalone dialog component while child is created from `ng-template`

Now, the problem is, that if I use `matDialogClose` inside `ng-template` parent dialog is closed, and child is intact.

Here is a stackblitz for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-vbxhc3

Main dialog template

```
<ng-template #nested>
    hey, i am nested dialog, close me with the button
    <button matDialogClose="someResult">CLOSE ME </button>
</ng-template>
```

opening child template

```
  @ViewChild("nested")
  nestedTmplateRef;
  private dialog:MatDialog
  ...
   this.dialog.open(this.nestedTmplateRef);
```

Can I close child dialog using `matCloseDialog` directive?? I am interested in using this solution as other obvious workarounds like controlling child dialog from component is know to me. However, using just directive would save me some boilerplace code. I am little bit rusty with angular material components and probably I dont see a obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a bug in material. If you check the code [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/dialog/dialog-content-directives.ts#L54) you can see the comment:

> When this directive is included in a dialog via TemplateRef (rather than being in a Component), the DialogRef isn't available via injection because embedded views cannot be given a custom injector. Instead, we look up the DialogRef by ID. This must occur in `onInit`, as the ID binding for the dialog container won't be resolved at constructor time.

However, when using a nested dialog, the method `getClosestDialog` does not seem to get the correct dialog.

I've made a sort of workaround for it though, and perhaps you can create a custom directive from this logic to make it reusable:

By adding a reference on the `MatDialogClose` and querying this in your component you can set the correct dialog reference:

```
<ng-template #nested>
  hey, i am nested dialog, close me with the button
  <button matDialogClose="someResult" #innerClose="matDialogClose">CLOSE ME </button>
</ng-template>
```

```
@ViewChild("nested")
nestedTmplateRef;

@ViewChild('innerClose')
close: MatDialogClose;

ngOnInit(){
  const ref = this.dialog.open(this.nestedTmplateRef);  

  // have to wait for the next tick so the `dialogRef` does not get overwritten again
  setTimeout(() => this.close.dialogRef = ref);
}
```

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-avg2vx?file=app/confirmation-dialog.component.ts)